# How to toggle class between elements using event.target?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating simple app using javaScript, i have to navigation link, i want to give them class uing `event.target`, i have two different functions, my goal is to toggle class name between this two navigation link, for example if i click home link, i want to give this link `.active` class, and if i click home2 i want to remove `.active` class from home link and give it to home2 link, i want to solve this problem using Vanilla JavaScript, any solution?

```js
function goHome(event){
 event.target.classList.add('active')
}

function goSomeWhere(event){
 event.target.classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<li onclick="goHome(event)" class="primery ">home</li>
<li onclick="goSomeWhere(event)" class="primary2">home2</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first remove the active class from any that it is applied to, and then apply it to the one the user has clicked on. That would look something like this:

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    menu.querySelectorAll('.active')
        .forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active');

    event.target.classList.add('active');
});
```

This should work assuming you put an id of `menu` onto your div, but I would suggest that you change the div to be a nav, since it's an element that's being used for navigation, and a div doesn't express that.

With this approach you can also remove the `onclick` attribute of the list items.